# Labels not defined in tkinter app

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5

I'm trying to make a basic window with the text "t" inside using Tkinter, however when running the code the shell spits out "NameError: name 'Label' is not defined". I'm running Python 3.5.2.

I followed the tutorials but the problem is in the `label = Label(root, text="test")` line.

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
sheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
swidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
root.minsize(width=swidth, height=sheight)
root.maxsize(width=swidth, height=sheight)

label = Label(root, text="test")
label1.pack()

root = mainloop()
```

Is the label function different in 3.5.2?

Comment: Did mean `tkinter.Label` due to how you imported it? `Label` is a *class*, not function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never imported the `Label` class. Try `tkinter.Label`

Check the import statements for those tutorials

Maybe they imply `from tkinter import *`

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
sheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
swidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
root.minsize(width=swidth, height=sheight)
root.maxsize(width=swidth, height=sheight)

label = tkinter.Label(root, text="test")
label1.pack()

root = tkinter.mainloop() # <- prob need to fix this as well.
```

Because you didn't do `from tkinter import *` you need to invoke the Label from the tkinter module.

Alternatively you can do:

```
from tkinter import *
...
label = Label(root, text="test")
```

Answer (score 0):

stumbled across the same Problem. Most beginners guides seem to mess up here.
I had to use a second line in the configuration:

## !/usr/bin/python3

import tkinter
from tkinter import *

...

Comment: You need to properly format the code in your answer. See [How do I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Operating System your code should run well but on macOS, you will get a problem. I don't know why something like that happen. Anyway try:

```
import tkinter, 
from tkinter import*
```

And run

After that just write:

```
from tkinter import *
```

or

```
import tkinter
```

(not both this time)

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo error...
Nothing to do with the import statements.

Label = with a capital L not l

Answer (score -2):

Label(root, text="Username").place(x=20,y=20)
capitalize l

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).